# Is it possible to use FlexSlider 2 for a both ltr and rtl side?

Tags: wordpress, right-to-left, flexslider

I've build a WordPress Theme and I'm currently working on rtl support. The slider breaks whenever I adjust the screen size in the browser, I see that there is an rtl version of FlexSlider 2, I'm if it's made for websites that switch between rtl and ltr or websites that use rtl exclusively? If it's the former how is it done?

First question here.

Answer (score 0):

The workout I used for this is to keep the slider as ltr in an rtl page and translate the page using a plugin. Only bummer to this method is the position of overlays in the slide wouldn't change so I just kept them in the middle.